# SQL-Server driver to access stored procedure or view source code

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view, odbc

Does anyone know if exists a SQL-Server driver in some language (python, java, c#, javascript..) which allows to inspect the souce code of a stored procedure or a view in a sql server database?

For example let's say in the db XXX i have the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MY_VIEW] AS
SELECT
    FIELD_1 AS X
    FIELD_2 AS Y
    FIELD_3 AS Z
FROM
    [XXX].[dbo].[MY_TABLE_SOURCE]
```

I need to retrieve the code above using some programming language (python preferred). Is it possible?

Comment: updated question, thanks

Comment: sp_helptext? sys.sql_modules?

Comment: @sepupic Thank you! sp_helptext works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

From @sepupic comment this solution works (python):

```
import pyodbc

DRIVER = "SQL Server"
DB_NAME = "mydb"
USR = "username"
PWD = "password"

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={0};SERVER=10.12.0.11;DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3}'.format(DRIVER, DB_NAME, USR, PWD))
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("EXECUTE SP_HELPTEXT N'MY_VIEW_OR_PROCEDURE'")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```